# Making git pushes from school blocked

Tags: git, github, obsidian

I'm currently using Obsidian.md to take notes for school, and I rely on Obsidian Git to back up and sync my notes. However, I've run into an issue because it seems that my school has blocked SSH traffic, which prevents me from safely backing up my notes.

I've already attempted to address this issue by setting the origin URL to an HTTPS URL, but I've encountered a problem with GitHub no longer supporting password authentication, which is the only method I know worked with HTTP. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem.

Additionally, I'm unable to convince my school to open port 22 to enable SSH traffic.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue and found a workaround for syncing Obsidian notes when SSH is blocked? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch from password to using a personal access token (that's essentially a special-purpose password for a specific use case), then HTTPS origin URLs should work: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

GitHub runs an SSH daemon listening on port 443 on a special hostname, `ssh.github.com`. (Port 443 is typically for HTTPS, so it's rarely blocked. GitLab and Bitbucket both do something similar, for the same reason.)

Test your connection with `ssh -Tp443 ssh.github.com`. If you get a reply mentioning your GitHub username, then that host:port tuple is open; otherwise, you'll need to use a personal access token (PAT) with HTTPS.

If that host:port tuple is open, then add this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
  HostName ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Your pushes will then use that hostname and port for GitHub.